# PYTHON Selenium: Click on a specific Dropdown containing Java

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I am having trouble selecting from a drop down list (two actually, Season and Date).  I can obtain the values which I want to input to the drop down selector, however am unable to understand what I need to do to be able to programmatically select from the dropdown.

This is the website which is of interest:
https://dataride.uci.ch/iframe/RankingDetails/1?disciplineId=10&groupId=1&momentId=19264&disciplineSeasonId=19&rankingTypeId=1&categoryId=22&raceTypeId=0

Here is the base code that I am using: (very sorry about the formatting, had trouble with long strings.)

```
`import requests
 from selenium import webdriver
 from time import sleep
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 url='https://dataride.uci.ch/iframe/RankingDetails/1?disciplineId=10&groupId=1&momentId=19264&disciplineSeasonId=19&rankingTypeId=1&categoryId=22&raceTypeId=0' browser=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='F:\Anaconda\chromedriver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

 browser.get(url) season_list=browser.find_element_by_id('seasons_listbox').get_attribute('textContent')dates_list=browser.find_element_by_id('dates_listbox').get_attribute('textContent').split('Ranking')[1]

for i in range(0,len(season_list),4):
    year=season_list[i:i+4]
    for j in range(0,len(dates_list),10):
        date=dates_list[j:j+10]
        print('YEAR: ',season_list[i:i+4],' DATE ',dates_list[j:j+10])`
```

Here is a screenshot of the two menus I would like to be able to iterate through:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code. I get the drop down menu using `xpath` and then use `send_keys`

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://dataride.uci.ch/iframe/RankingDetails/1?disciplineId=10&groupId=1&momentId=19264&disciplineSeasonId=19&rankingTypeId=1&categoryId=22&raceTypeId=0'

driver.get(url)
xpath_season = '//*[@id="ranking-details-view"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/span'
season = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_season)

xpath_date = '//*[@id="ranking-details-view"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[3]/span'
date = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_date)

season.send_keys('2016')
date.send_keys('31/12/2015')
```

If you want to select the `option` from the drop down list then you need to get the whole list.

Comment: Worked like a charm, I greatly appreciate the assistance with this!...  I would assume that if I wanted to cycle through all of the pages (they only report 1-50 riders per page) I would just need to apply the same methodology as you have done?

Comment: just send different values using `send_keys`